# why can't I put "cout <<" as a function argument in for_each?

Tags: c++, stl

```
std::vector<int> my_ints;
my_ints.push_back(1);
my_ints.push_back(2);
my_ints.push_back(3);
my_ints.push_back(4);

std::for_each(my_ints.begin(), my_ints.end(), std::cout.operator <<);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because that's a member function, and `for_each` wants a function object that takes a single parameter.

You'll have to write your own function:

```
void print_to_stdout(int i)
{
    std::cout << i;
}
std::for_each(my_ints.begin(), my_ints.end(), print_to_stdout);
```

Another alternative is to mix `std::mem_fun` and `std::bind1st` (or any of the better C++0x/boost alternatives) to generate that function.

But the best would be to use `std::copy` with a `std::ostream_iterator`:

```
std::copy(my_ints.begin(), my_ints.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout));
```

Answer (score 3):

`std::for_each` requires a function that has a single parameter, the element of the container you are iterating over.  However, `operator <<` requires two parameters, the left hand side and the right hand side of the operator.  So things don't line up.

You have to somehow bind the ostream parameter so that you are down to a single parameter again.  `boost::bind` is one way, or you can just define a custom, single argument function and pass that.

Answer (score 2):

for_each accepts a function as the last argument to apply on the elements of the range, 
defining a function should do what you what

```
void print(int i){
  cout << i << endl;
}
```

then

```
for_each(vector.begin(), vector.end(), print)
```

if this is what you are trying...